# UIPageViewController call zoom X1 before viewControllerAfterViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I want to reset zoom factor applied to imageView/scrollView before calling viewControllerAfterViewController.
I have an UIPageViewController "SecondViewController" and another UIViewController "ImageViewController". To explain hierarchy I prefer show some code :

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize pageViewController;
@synthesize imgModelArray; 

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return imgModelArray.count;
}
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 40/255.0 green:40/255.0 blue:40/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    // Init model and pageViewController
     self.imgModelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"piaggo.jpg":@"softCat"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"crumble.jpg":@"funnyDog"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"piaggo.jpg":@"sleepingCat"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"crumble.jpg":@"goodDog"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"piaggo.jpg":@"softCat"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"crumble.jpg":@"funnyDog"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"piaggo.jpg":@"sleepingCat"],
                  [[ImageModel alloc] initWith:@"crumble.jpg":@"goodDog"], nil];
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]  initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                      navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                   options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0f] forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey]];    
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    // Init ImageViewController - Load Model - Create page 1
    ImageViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
    imageViewController.model = [imgModelArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:imageViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;

 }

// Return an ImageViewController with previous data model
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)vcFrom
{
    ImageViewController *imgVc = (ImageViewController *)vcFrom;
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [imgModelArray indexOfObject:[imgVc model]];
    if (currentIndex == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    ImageViewController *previousImgViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
    previousImgViewController.model = [imgModelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

    return previousImgViewController;
}

// Return an ImageViewController with next data model
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)vcFrom
{
    ImageViewController *imgVc = (ImageViewController *)vcFrom;
    [imgVc zoomX1];
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [imgModelArray indexOfObject:[imgVc model]];
    if (currentIndex == imgModelArray.count - 1)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    ImageViewController *nextImgViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];    
    nextImgViewController.model = [imgModelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];
    return nextImgViewController;  
}

@end
```

I want to call zoomX1 method (localized in ImageViewController.m), just before this one : "viewControllerAfterViewController"
What kind of event could do this ?

zoomX1 work well excepted when I am using viewControllerAfterViewController.
When I call zoomx1 inside "viewControllerAfterViewController", my view is disappearing...
But the values for height and width are not 0. Help me please !

In ImageViewController.m : zoomX1

```
- (void)zoomX1{
    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to X1
    UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:model.imageName];
    CGSize currentImgSize = currentImage.size;

    CGFloat w = currentImgSize.width;
    CGFloat h = currentImgSize.height;
    CGFloat x = 0;
    CGFloat y = 0;    
    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}
```

EDITED (2X) :

I think I have a problem with UIPanGestureRecognizer.

In "SecondViewController.view" and "pageViewController" : PanGesture is used to move to next/previous "ImageViewController" with "viewControllerAfterViewController" and "viewControlleBeforeViewController"

In "ImageViewController.scrollView" : PanGesture is used to move to a specific area when I zoomed on an image.

I didn't add programmatically a PanGesture. I just want to keep the panGesture inside scrollView which is reponsible of moving inside an Image. And keep the other panGesture linked at view level which is responsible of switching page. I think they are private Apple's method.

But when I pan inside scrollView there is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in one of my projects and what I did I added an extra target to the UISwipeGestureRecognizer of the UIPageViewController. You can try this (it may be a considered by other developers a hack but I don't think so).

In viewDidLoad or other init/setup methods you can try something like this:

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in yourPageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
     if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) { 
        [gesture addTarget:self action:@selector(zoomX1)]
     }
}
```

Comment: I put a breakpoint on *if line* and it is never reached... I tried for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.view.gestureRecognizers){   and for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers){ and added it at last lines in viewdidload...I don't understand how I could move to next and previous page with zero UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: @icewall0 OH, I think there is no UISwipeGestureRecognizer, I think is a UIPanGestureRecognizer because the UIPageViewController also works when the user drags the finger over it. So you should check for the UIPanGestureRecognizer not UISwipeGestureRecognizer. But you have to check for the UIPageViewController's gestures recignizers. Please check it and let me know if it's working

Comment: NSUInteger nbr = self.view.gestureRecognizers.count;
    NSUInteger nbr2 = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers.count;   0 twice :'(

Comment: It seems that you are calling the method before your UIPageViewController is loaded. The gestureRecognizers property of UIPageViewController is working(I tested) and it's definitely working. Also you can check (just to see that the UIPageViewController has gestures) in `viewControllerAfter/viewControllerBefore` methods

Comment: I realized without changing my first code than If I go to page -2 or page +2... Zoomed image in Page 0 is automatically resized to zoomX1.

Comment: Well you are calling the `zoomX1` method from the `viewControllerAfter/viewControllerBefore` so it should be called for some cases.

Comment: //[imgVc zoomX1]; I commented this line viewControllerAfter/viewControllerBefore... Maybe there are only previous and next view which are caching by default inside a PageViewController. But you learned me a good way to find a UIGestureRecognizer and change its default selector. I am sure I will use it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30441/discussion-between-icewall0-and-danypata)